# Personal Macro Workbook has gone missing (AGAIN)!

Tags: excel, vba

I don´t understand why, but it´s the second or third time I've lost my Personal Workbook with all my macro copies. The only different thing that I've done was editing a macro but, when excel was closing, I haven't saved the changes. Next time I've opened excel, surprise, surprise, no Personal Workbook! Has anyone had the same problem? Does anyone know why it happens? I have already searched in (I believe so) all possible folders where It could be stored.

Thanks!

Comment: When you look in "Recent Documents" is it there? If you try to open it will it work/

Comment: but you shouldn't be worry- it's rather close but not deleted. You need to search Personal.XLSB on your disk and run it to have it back. I used to have such problem using Excel 2007 but can't remember what solved that issue.

Comment: Is's not in Recent Documents, user2140261. KazJaw, I have already searched Personal.xlsb and found nothing.

Comment: Take a look at this folder: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office 10\XLStart` (Or the equivalent based on the version of Excel you are running.)

Comment: Nothing, guitarthrower.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\XLSTART

Answer (score 8):

the file can be found for 2007/2010 users in :

> C:\Users\User ID\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

or somewhere similar for others.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

The folder where the personal macros are saved can be found by using the command:

`?Application.StartupPath` (without `""` sign) in VBA.

Open VBA (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and enter the command in the field on the bottom.

Hope this helped

Comment: Worked great-- 1) Open VBA: `ALT+F11`, 2) Paste this script into the Excel VBA immediate window: `?Application.StartupPath`, 3) Copy file path, 4) open windows file explorer and paste in file path, 5) Double click the file `PERSONAL.XLSB`, 6) Check excel macros and they should be there.My file was found here: `C:\Users\bl0040\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`

Answer (score 1):

Using `Microsoft office 365`.  Lost `Excel` and `Word` Macros during last update.  Had an Excel File that I had copied to my laptop (`Windows 10`) which had not been updated.  Brought it up on my desktop.  Was able to see modules but no content.  Was unable to remove modules.  Uninstalled `Office 365`.  After reinstall, was able to see and use macros from that file.  Word macro not retrieved.  Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Mine went missing completely and was not in the xlstart folder. I finally discovered it was because I'm on a work server, files are all network storage based, and I had just changed my network password. I think the mis-match caused my links to personal files to be temporarily broken. I logged out completely, and back in, and everything was back where it should be.

In short: I tried turning it off and turning it back on again.

Answer (score 0):

For those using MacOS / OSX (El Capitan) with Excel 2016 I located my copy of `Personal Macro Workbook.xlsb`, which I had previously unhidden in Excel, then closed, in the following location:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Application Support/User/Personal Macro Workbook.xlsb
```

Please note that I used multiple search functions within OSX which did not return this file in the search results for some reason.